# How to change WebSphere Portal URL from ibmhttp to w3?

Tags: url, websphere-portal

I installed a `WebSphere Portal 8` and in this installation

1. I have one server as http server,
2. one server for Domino server as LDAP
3. one server for Portal 8.

Now the Portal URL is `ibmhttp.XXX.com` and I need to change it to `w3.XXX.com`
Can anybody help me how to do it?  Is it simply changing the computer name hosting the web server to `w3`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should reference http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21569040
it discusses the changing of your WebSphere Portal name.

if you want to add a subportal at a URL, that's different and documented in the Portal 8 Infocenter http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+WebSphere+Portal+8+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Human_readable_URL_mappings_for_virtual_portals_wp8&content=pdcontent